# Integration between google hangout and other framework

Tags: integration, google-plus, google-hangouts

I am working on google hangout app since last couple of week.
And it looks good feature of the google for hangout.

I tried to search on web for google hangout's api for integrate with other framework , but i can't able to search that.

SO, Is that possible to integrate google hangout with other framework like Struts, Spring etc ?

Is google hangout API jar available ?

Answer (score 0):

The hangout API is purely a client-side API that runs in JavaScript and uses HTML to display its results. You should be able to use most JavaScript frameworks and libraries with it.

Struts and Spring are Java server-side frameworks. While the Hangout API can't work with them directly, you can certainly use them to provide server-side support for your Hangout app for things like creating the dynamic html (though jsp or jsf) for the Hangout app or for the app to communicate with the server via AJAX or equivalent.

For these, you should not need a Hangout API JAR, and none exist.